# How can I delete data with Cursor in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have an Android database. I have read data from my database with cursor

```
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(SmartProbeDBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, SmartProbeDBOpenHelper.columns, null, new String[]{}, null, null, null);
```

Now I want to delete data, which I read with my cursor. That means what I read with my cursor.

**Note:** I have two background service with AsyncTask. One service Write into the DB and the other one read and delete the rows.

How can I do it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delete certain rows

```
String whereClauseWithoutTheWhere = "_id = ?";
String[] params =new String[]{100,151};
boolean succeeded = sqLiteDatabase.delete(SmartProbeDBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,whereClauseWithoutTheWhere,params)>0;
```

to delete all rows your whereClause needs to be null